# Joomla 3 Intro Image Selector Administration Panel Error

Tags: joomla, photo, administration

I recently created a fresh install off Joomla 3 on a couple of servers. I have an unusual problem with one of the installations. When I create new articles I go to select the intro image, the file browser appears as expected, however in the thumbnail display each image appears on it's own line, this makes browsing through the images more difficult.

The images below show how it should look and how it appears on my site, I don't have the rep to post images so please see the image in the link below:

[image: Comparison with working media manager]

The left shows how it normally appears with each thumbnail appearing in a grid, on the right it appears in a list style, with a lot of wasted unused space. Any suggestions on what might be causing this? Or as a last resort I good alternative extension which I could install over the default option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is known bug in Joomla 3.0 caused by using Bootstrap in an iframe.

*short explaination: Bootstrap window is narrower than typical computer screen, so layout is adapted to low resolution screens (thus thumbnails are one under another).*

See  Joomla Issue tracker: [[#29377] Image select](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=29377) for more details and how to fix it yourself or update to 3.1 where bug should have been fixed.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will look into it and report back, seems a little odd it would only affect one site when both sites I own are running similar templates with bootstraps. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking your browsers console for errors.

Likely culprits are a CSS file couldn't be loaded or a Javascript error (possibly from the file not being found/loaded).

If you can find any errors and update you answer, we can provide more constructive feedback.

Comment: I agree. It often happens when you load some extra plugin or administrator module that carelessly loads an extra css file.